# Getting error in production environment, running fine in localhost

Tags: php, jquery

I have total 6 multiple select lists when i select any one or multiple option from these lists i will show them after form submission, initially they hidden.
Below is my script this is works fine in localhost but i am getting syntax error in production 
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'isset'(T_ISSET). Please someone help me, Thanks in advance

```
    <script>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['LS_name']) && !empty(isset($_POST['LS_name']))) { ?>
            $('.mystaff_opt1').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if(isset($_POST['FamilyIncome']) && !empty(isset($_POST['FamilyIncome']))){ ?>
        $('.mystaff_opt2').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if(isset($_POST['Religion']) && !empty(isset($_POST['Religion']))){ ?>
        $('.mystaff_opt3').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if(isset($_POST['Category']) && !empty(isset($_POST['Category']))){ ?>
        $('.mystaff_opt4').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if(isset($_POST['Gender']) && !empty(isset($_POST['Gender']))){ ?>
        $('.mystaff_opt5').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if(isset($_POST['State']) && !empty(isset($_POST['Gender']))){ ?>
        $('.mystaff_opt6').collapse('show');
    <?php } ?>  
    </script>
```

Comment: compare `error_reporting()` of your localhost & server.

Comment: and do not mix php with JavaScript (jQuery) define before php varaible as js and then your code is more readable and easier to find an error (but in posted code there is no errors)

Comment: i have server error log but how to get localhost errors. I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your code is quite right:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['LS_name']) && !empty(isset($_POST['LS_name']))) { ?>
```

This is testing if the variable is set (which it is if you get to the second condition) and then tests !empty(true)

Perhaps that should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['LS_name']) && !empty($_POST['LS_name'])) {
```

Lastly - which line is the error reporting.  Check carefully the bracketing and quotes being used on that line.